# SwiftUI not refresh my custom UIView with UIViewRepresentable & ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, observableobject, uiviewrepresentable

I have

1. created a simple `ARClass: ObservableObject` with `@Published var name: String`
2. created a custom `ARView: UIView` that receives `ARClass` as a
   parameter and draws a `Text` view displaying `ARClass.name` in the center
3. created `UIViewRepresentable`

and then used in SwiftUI `View` by using `ARClass(color: .red, name: "Test Text")` as an environment object in `SceneDelegate`

```swift
class ARClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bg: UIColor
    @Published var name: String
    
    init(color: UIColor, name: String) {
        self.bg = color
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ARViewX: UIViewRepresentable {
    var ar: ARClass
    var frame: CGRect
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        uiView.frame = frame
        uiView.ar = ar
        uiView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        ARView(ar: ar, frame: frame)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var ar: ARClass
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                ARViewX(ar: self.ar, frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height/3)))
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                Text(self.ar.name)
                Divider()
                TextField("Name", text: self.$ar.name)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I edited the `TextField`, the whole body is refreshed except the `UIViewRepresentable`. It always resets the 'name' variable to its initial value.

Answer (score 7):

After hours finally I know that the `updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context)` in `UIViewRepresentable` never got called so I modified the `ARClass` like this:

```swift
class ARClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bg: UIColor
    @Published var name: String {
        didSet {
            if let onNameChange = onNameChange {
                onNameChange()
            }
        }
    }
    var onNameChange: (()->Void)?
    init(color: UIColor, name: String) {
        self.bg = color
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And the `UIViewRepresentable` like this:

```swift
func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
    uiView.frame = frame
    ar.onNameChange = {
        uiView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe that there isn't a better solution like this. But I haven't found one either. It's not very SwiftUI-ish.

Comment: I have almost the same problem: For me updateUIView gets called the first time I update the model but not on any following updates.

Comment: Doesn't work for me